# Right procedure for contributing or suggesting feature/improvements

Tags: openmdao

I would like to expose some COBYLA options to the problem.driver input. I have implemented few lines in the two methods in the driver:

~/OpenMDAO/openmdao/drivers/scipy_optimizer.py 
(see below)

Even though this works as it should (i.e. prob.driver.options['initstep'] = 3.), I am not sure if such a feature should be there or if this is right way to do this. Because I can see the note in desc = "For detailed control, use solver-specific options."

How are these kind of development/simple feature issues are supposed to be handled?

```
   class ScipyOptimizeDriver(Driver):   
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
        def _declare_options(self):
            self.options.declare('initstep', default=1., types=float,
                                 desc='COBYLA: Reasonable initial changes to the variables')



        def run(self):
     ...
     ...
     ...
            if opt == 'COBYLA':
                self.opt_settings['rhobeg'] = self.options['initstep']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can submit a pull request on the [OpenMDAO github page](https://github.com/openmdao/openmdao/pulls). The development team out of NASA Glenn Research Center will perform a code review, and either accept it as is or make requests for changes.

Thanks for your interest in the project!

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if I am supposed to create the pull request only via online changes. Because I cloned the repo, crated a branch and the push request to the openmdao repo was not permitted.

Comment: you can't push directly to the OpenMDAO repo. You need to make your own fork of the repo on github, push to that. Then you can make the PR from there

Comment: I think it went through. Thanks for your guidance.